# Radiation dangerous or not?

Tags: dna

I've always been told that most electronic devices such as WiFi/phones/laptops and such emit a non-ionizing radiation which is completely fine as it does not damage human DNA. I've been googling and i see people arguing about it but there seems to be no evidence to back up the fact that it's not damaging. I'm just curious is what I'm saying correct? or can it damage the human body as i see people mention it can lead to pretty serious health problems.

Comment: WIfi and phones emit radio waves, you you might want to ask about that specifically, all non-ionizing radiation is too big a spectrum to cover in a meaningful answer.